# Classes not showing up in console: es6 and meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using `grigio:babel` to transpile es6 in meteor. I have a simple file called `camera.es6` to provide camera functionality

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  class Camera {
    constructor() {
    }
    getStream() {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ video: true }, resolve, reject);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I then go into my browser console and try to instance a new camera.

```
var c = new Camera()
VM1898:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Camera is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:13
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Shouldn't camera be available? Babel seems to say that it should just translate it to a function-like structure to make it work in ES5. I also tried to run it in babel's repl [and it translated perfectly fine](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Camera%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.%24el%20%3D%20%24(element)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getStream()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise(function%20(resolve%2C%20reject)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(%7B%20video%3A%20true%20%7D%2C%20resolve%2C%20reject)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

How do I access my classes with meteor and es6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose babel wrap all you code into a closure, so you are unable to reach Camera from console. Try to do something like this

```
window.Camera = Camera;
```

After class definition

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Out of curiosity, do you know if they have a namespace for that closure that can be accessed?

Comment: I dont know how babel works. But i think it uses CommonJS modules, so it wraps all your files in separate closures. To access inner stuff from console you have to use this dirty trick. Personally i recommend to you - use debugger, You can write debugger keyword right in your code and browser will stop code running in this place and in your console you will be inside current context.

Comment: You may also want to put this into a package and export `Camera`, instead of putting it in the global closure.

Comment: `grigio:babel` doesn't support CommonJS modules yet. The upcoming ES6 integration with Meteor 1.2 will.